# Very bad SQLite performance on Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime

I have a Windows Phone 8 Application that uses a SQLite database. To access the database, I use the WinRT Wrapper by Andy Wigley ([source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andy_wigley/archive/2013/06/06/sqlite-winrt-database-programming-on-windows-phone-and-windows-8.aspx))

My database is very simple, only one table: 
Locations: integer primary key "FieldIndex", varchar "Field1", varchar "Field2", varchar "Field3", varchar "Field4", varchar "Field5", varchar "Field6", int "CategoryID"

I also have a index on both "FieldIndex" and "CategoryID".

There are in total 4000 entries in the table with the database being 900 kB in size. I have also compacted the database (vacuum). The database is deployed to the phone as application content (= in the installation folder = read-only). I only use the database for Queries. My data access code looks like this:

```
using (var db = new SQLiteWinRTPhone.Database(Package.Current.InstalledLocation, @"Model\db.sqlite"))
{
    await db.OpenAsync(SQLiteWinRTPhone.SqliteOpenMode.OpenRead);
    await db.ExecuteStatementAsync("PRAGMA journal_mode = MEMORY");
    await db.ExecuteStatementAsync("PRAGMA temp_store =  2;");

    using (var stmt = await db.PrepareStatementAsync("SELECT * FROM Locations;"))
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (await stmt.StepAsync())
        {
            // There is nothing happening here
            // Just for testing. In my real code, I iterate on all rows and store them in a object. I wanted isolate the issue here.
            i++;
        }
    }
    MessageBox.Show("We read " + i.toString() + " records.");
}
```

At the moment, the above statement takes 20 seconds to complete. From my standpoint, this is unacceptable. I tried to profile my application and the hotpath is in the native code libaries (mostly ConcRT related). The WinRT wrapper is compiled as "release" and I don't understand why the performance is so bad.

**GOAL**: I want to read all rows and store them in a object for binding to my view, searching, etc. and so on.

Any ideas what I could do to make my database queries somewhat acceptable (< 5 seconds)?

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(0) FROM Location`?

Comment: @spender SELECT COUNT(0) FROM Locations; -> 4000

Comment: I think spender means to use `SELECT COUNT(0) FROM Location` and get the return of that query rather than querying everything in the table and then just counting the rows that were returned.

Comment: @Tory Sorry, big missunderstanding (will post a remark). I don't want to get the count of rows. I want to iterate on all rows. I just stripped out the code to make it as easy as possible. The "i" variable is just for testing.

Comment: I think it may be that you are grabbing each row asynchronously.  As far as I understand it, queries are supposed to run all in one go, where as you are forcing the SQL Server to stop every time it has a new row to return.  Have you tried the non-async versions of the Execute Commands, if there are any?

Comment: @Tory The WinRT wrapper provided by the Windows Phone Team only has async methods.

Comment: @Jasper Could you try just having your counting code (i.e. just like what you have here) and timing that to see if querying the database is slowing down your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main fault for the horrible performance is the WinRT wrapper by Microsoft, which has bad performance by default. Always use the following way to select and insert in loops:

```
await stmt.StepAsync().AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false))
```

More details: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andy_wigley/archive/2013/11/21/how-to-massively-improve-sqlite-performance-using-sqlwinrt.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I dont' know what is wrong with your code. 
You can also try to use another wrapper for example c#-sqlite + sqlite-net ORM. https://github.com/peterhuene/sqlite-net-wp8 I have used it for my project and performance was very good.