# SQLite SELECT very slow on Windows Phone

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

Simple SQLite SELECT query on Windows Phone is very slow on a high-end device (Lumia 930).

```
select * from tableName
```

It's fetching around 15000 records (yeah, I need them all) and normally I'd expect it to not be this slow. However, it takes around 12-13 seconds to get all the records. I'm using SQLite.Net-PCL client.

What could be causing it? Is it true that it's [due to the very slow wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17426679/very-bad-sqlite-performance-on-windows-phone-8)? Is there a workaround, any way to improve it?

EDIT: I tried using [SQLite PCL from Microsoft Open Technologies](https://sqlitepcl.codeplex.com/) and I manually mapped property by property and I got much better results. So it seems that the count of rows, count of columns and the reflection, all combined, cause things to slow down. I am now working on trying to expose a similar functionality through SQLite.NET-PCL, the library which I'm using, to see how that would go.

EDIT2: I marked Peter's answer as answer to my question as I was able to improve performance dramatically by manually mapping type by type using Prepare call and stepping through row by row.

Comment: Why do you need them all in one go, do you need all the columns. I wouldn't do this unless I had no choice at all on a high end server...

Comment: Your app is really capable of displaying the information of all 15000 records on the phone's screen at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite can easily return 15,000 records from a simple table in a fraction of a second on a Windows Phone (tested on a Lumia 920).

There are other things causing your poor performance. If you have a huge number of columns, that might be a problem. Depending on how the SQLite wrapper is implemented (I don't know), two possible culprits are use of Reflection to fill your result objects or per-row `Async` overhead. But again, I don't know how that wrapper is implemented specifically.

The way to speed it up (other than to return less data) is to write your code in C++ and wrap it in a WinRT component to be called by your managed app.

Comment: Can you tell me which libraries and which wrapper (exact versions, if possible) did you use to verify that you can get 15000 queries so quickly? I'd like to try it too, and see if those are causing the issue for me. I tried reducing the number of columns to only 2, but it still takes 3 seconds, which is still pretty bad (and I don't have all the data I need :) )

Comment: The way to get the best performance is to not use a wrapper - write directly against the C API. I'm using my own custom library running against SQLite 3.8.7.4

Comment: I am marking this as answer as doing a manual mapping of types helped me improve performance dramatically.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what information you want from your entities you may try using `Query<>()` method that alows you to write raw SQL query and then you can select only fields that you are interested in and map it to lighter entities if that is possible, even if you getting all fields for your entitiy `Query<>()` still should be quicker.
Also check if you are using lates SQLite driver for WP

Comment: I am already using `Query<T>` to execute a raw query. I am not using the latest SQLite driver because the latest one is throwing SQLite logic error when doing UpdateAll/InsertAll, but I tried using it just for the query and it takes the same time to get the entities.